# What do window objects (window.something = something) do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I don't know if you need to see the full code, but I have seen a few plugins that do this:

```
window.dataValidate = dataValidate
```

Does this add 'dataValidate' to the window object, or how does it work?

Comment: It copies `dataValidate` to a global variable with the same name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does this add 'dataValidate' to the window object

Yes, it will.

For example, if you're inside another scope;

```
function foo() {
    var bar = 4;

    window.bar = bar;
}
```

You've now made `bar` global, and can access it from *anywhere*. Without the `window.bar = bar`, you'd only have been able to access it within `foo()`.

You'll commonly see this being used at the end of an IIFE, to *publish* work to the rest of the world (e.g. [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/6190370ab7406b526c29cda0a4c8301b6a259660/src/exports.js#L23));

```
(function () {
   var jQuery;

   // Setup jQuery

   window.jQuery = jQuery;
}());
```

You might see people doing this instead;

```
function foo() {
    bar = 4; // Note the lack of `var`
}
```

This has the same effect through the use of "implied globals"; but it will throw an *error* in ES5 strict mode, and is generally considered a bad practice (*did the programmer mean to make it global, or did they simply accidentally omit `var`?*).

Comment: It will only throw an error in ES5 strict mode - in the non-strict mode of the ES5 specification it won't.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: Haha, thanks for the correction... my brain was writing "ES5 strict mode", but seems my keyboard had other ideas ;).

Comment: or one part of your brain was thinking strict and the other was eating it :-)

Comment: I feel like the reason why this is useful is completely missing here ("why not just make it global in the first place?"): Using a scope to setup your objects you can make sure that you won't make anything global that is supposed to be "private" (utility functions, private variables, …). With the assignment to `window` in the end you have easy control over what you actually export (= make global), plus you can easily change the *way* you are making it global (renaming, putting it into a different namespace, …).